# Initialize vector of my own class type

Tags: c++, vector, c++11

I'm trying to declare a static vector of my own class type (**SY::Symbol**) like this:

**SymbolsTable.h**

```
namespace SYT
{
    class SymbolsTable
    {
        public:
            static std::vector<SY::Symbol> m_symbols;
                    void addToken(TK::Token);
    };
}
```

and I want to use it inside the method addToken in my *SymbolsTable.cpp* file.

**SymbolsTable.cpp**

```
#include "../../includes/px/SymbolsTable.h"
#include "../../includes/px/Token.h"

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::vector<SY::Symbol> SYT::SymbolsTable::m_symbols(std::initializer_list<SY::Symbol>);

SYT::SymbolsTable::SymbolsTable()
{

}

void SYT::SymbolsTable::addToken(TK::Token token)
{
    int index = getSymbolIndex(token); 

    if(index == -1)
    {
        SY::Symbol symb(token, "");
        SYT::SymbolsTable::m_symbols.push_back(symb);
        token.setIndex(indexOf(m_symbols, symb)); 
    }
    else
    {
        token.setIndex(index);
    }       
}
```

I've tried declaring and initializing it outside the class inside my *SymbolsTable.cpp*, but I guet the error.

> error: no 'std::vector
>   SYT::SymbolsTable::m_symbols(std::initializer_list)'
>   member function declared in class 'SYT::SymbolsTable'

As you can see, I have to initialize it, so I'm trying to use this `initializer_list`, which I don't know if I'm doing it correct.

So, I know that I have to initialize the vector before everything.

**My question is:**

- where to initialize it;
- how to inialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just write

```
std::vector<SY::Symbol> SYT::SymbolsTable::m_symbols;
```

in the cpp file.

this uses the default constructor, initializing the vector to an empty vector.

however, most likely you don't really want a static *member*, because it feels very wrong to have non-static member functions update a static data member. rather you probably want a static *instance* of the class. and even that is probably a sub-optimal design, but still probably an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::initializer_list<SY::Symbol>
```

This is a type so the compiler is reading this as a function definition which has not been declared in the specified scope, thus the error.

You can write

```
std::vector<SY::Symbol> SYT::SymbolsTable::m_symbols;
```

To just define it, or

```
std::vector<SY::Symbol> SYT::SymbolsTable::m_symbols{1,2,3,4};
```

to initialize it - note replace 1-4 with valid `SY::Symbol` objects.